# Background service to process requests in queue with delay in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not even sure how this should be asked but here is my scenario:

I have a list of records which are updated or refreshed from time to time. For some of these records I want to call a API to fetch some date. The problem is that the API has some limits, let's say for example only 100 calls per hour.

I need a mechanism to:

- run in the background and check if there are new records to process
- if there are new records split them into 100 chunks and then on each 1 hour call the API with each 100 records
- on next check, if there are new records, append them and so on

What would be the best way to achieve this in node.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prerequisite**

Keeping records in memory, especially when there is an unknown amount to be register, is bad practice. In order for this pseudo-example to work, you would need a collection/table of these records with all their current values + it needs to have a field `.isChecked=false`. This way the database query will return the first 100 unchecked records and we do not need to manage it on the application level.

---

First off, we need a scheduler in order to trigger the task every 1 h exactly. For this we will utilize cron-jobs `npm install cron` docs can be found [here](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron)

Create 3 files: API.js, checker.js, cron.js

**cron.js** - scheduler file (best triggered post-app-boot)

```
let CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
let DB = require('some-DB');

let APIChecker = require('./checker.js');
let APICheckerInstance = APIChecker({url: "http://my-api.com"});

var job = new CronJob('00 00 * * * *', function() {
    //exeute script for every hour ( 00 secod mark, 0 minute mark, every hour)
    let records = DB.get("records which have isChecked=false").toArray(); //pseudo code
    APIChecker.check(records, function (err, result=null) {
        // handle callback/ can return results or error
        // DB.massUpdate(result)
    })
}, function () {
    console.log("Job has finished");
});
```

**chcker.js** - Logic for checking/modifying data

```
'use strict';

const
    util = require('util'),
    API = require('./api.js');

module.exports = function (options) {

    function MyAPIChecker (options) {
        this.result = [];
        API.call(this, options);
    }

    util.inherits(MyAPIChecker, API);

    MyAPIChecker.prototype.check = function (records, callback) {
        this.result = [];
        let temp = records.length;

        for(let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            this.makeRequest(records[i])
                .then(result => {
                    records[i].isChecked = true;
                    // add stuff from result
                    // or return stuff with callback for processing
                    if (!--temp) return callback(null, records)
                })
        }
    }
    return new MyAPIChecker(options);
}
```

api.js - API reserved for HTTP request

```
'use strict';

const
    request = require('your-request-lib');

module.exports = (function () {

    function API (options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    API.prototype.prepareRequest = function (record) {
        // prepare http(s) options;
        // get URL and such from this.options ( pass it to the constructor )
        // use record data
        return options
    }

    API.prototype.makeRequest = function (record) {
        let opts = this.prepareRequest(record);
        // or any other verb
        return request.get(opts);
    }

    return API;
})()
```

Hope you will find this example useful.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer